# Why source same script twice is exiting the shell?

Tags: bash, shell-script, source, subshell

I have written a bash script to create a git worktree- `cr_wt`

```
#!/bin/bash

unset CDET_ID
unset WT_DIR

source ~/.bashrc

usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $0 [ -c CDET_ID ] [ -d Directory Name ]"
    exit 2
}

while getopts 'c:d:h' flag
do
    case $flag in
        c) CDET_ID=$OPTARG ;;
        d) WT_DIR=$OPTARG ;;
        h) usage
    esac
done

if [[ -n $CDET_ID ]] && [[ -n $WT_DIR ]]
then
    cd $REPO
    git worktree add -b $CDET_ID.my_branch $WT_DIR origin/my_branch 
    cd $WT_DIR
    WS="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
else
    usage
fi
```

I launch this script like -
`. cr_wt -c <cdet_id> -d <dir_name>`

I am actually sourcing it, since I can save the `$WS` which stores the root directory of my git repository. And there are many alias of mine which rely on `$WS` to navigate within the repository. Since I want to set `$WS` to the new directory which is created as git worktree. I source this script.

The problem that I am facing is - after I run/source this script like -
`. cr_wt -c <cdet_id> -d <dir_name>`

git worktree gets created. After which if I source the script again like -
`. cr_wt -c <cdet_id> -d <dir_name>`

then the bash shell is getting exited.

Comment: [A] Your case h) is missing the ;; [B] Sourcing `.bashrc` twice into your main shell is probably not a great idea. [C] Good idea to quote all substitutions. [D] Because it is sourced, the `exit 2` in usage will exit your main shell, so it is probably usage being called. Add some printfs to see where it reaches, and verify syntax through shellcheck.net.

Comment: [D] you mentioned since it is sourced usage() is called - you are saying. If that was the case, when I first sourced why is it working?

Comment: replace `exit 2` with `echo exiting... && sleep 10 && exit 2` then you will notice it

Comment: Sorry, mixed up two things. (1) Sourcing the file means the `exit` would be actioned in the main shell. So I suspect `usage` is being called on the second execution, because that is the only exit I can see (I assume you would notice if the main shell exited itself). (2) No idea what is in your .bashrc -- you might write a debug script  that just repeats that one line. Likewise, usage() is also sourced when it is already defined. (3) Debug prints before and after the .bashrc, and each call of usage, might narrow down the cause. (4) Without quotes, an option with spaces will throw `not found`.